# parse json with php 5 not working

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse and list a json file. I have it as Unicode-8 without BOM. File is operational. Structure:

```
// "games.json" :
// {"data":[
// {"game":"5359","Date":"07/08/2015"},
// {"game":"5355","Date":"10/20/2007"},
....


<?php

// copy file content into a string var
$jsondata = file_get_contents("games.json");

// convert the string to a json object
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

var_dump($json); // DW!

foreach($json["data"] as $data_X)

{echo $data_X->game;} 
?>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: *Why doesn't this work?* - what is happening now? `var_dump($json);` - see what you are getting.

Comment: are the comments and leading "games.json" part of the file.

Comment: Are you passing json data as variable or something else..?

Comment: var_dump($json); displays nothing. The external file "games.json" is fine. Just can't be processed due to the bad code I created. What was my mistake?

Comment: This looks like the files content is _not_ json, but contains a list of separate entries (rows), who might be json. In that case you will have to separate the entries first and can then `json_decode()` each single entry.

Comment: var_dump() now works! But how do I use this associative array to display and format specific fields?

Comment: The file "games.json" is AFAIK perfect JSON because it is read and parsed by dataTables.

Comment: I will work on this. I think I see light at the end of the tunnel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" }';
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

use `$json = json_decode($jsondata);` instead of `$json = json_decode($jsondata,true); True parameter convert it into array not json object.